# after click and load page jquery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to know how to execute two events in jquery. So, after I click button and page ends loading then show alert.
My function is,

```
$("#upload").click(function(){
$(window).bind("load",function(){
alert("done"); });});
```

So any suggestion Thanks.The button is submit button to upload a csv file to mysql. So after i submit then page has end loaded, the alert massage will show.

Comment: So you want to only be able to click the button once the page is loaded? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: usually you bind the click event in the domready event

Comment: not the other way around

Comment: I think he wants to click a button on his page, sth happens and after its done, he wants to do something. But I guess that depends on what hes doing onclick, so we need some more details

Comment: The button is submit button to upload, csv file to mysql. So after i submit then page has end loaded, the alert massage will show.

Comment: @user3744203 So you want an alert after the csv upload.

Comment: is your upload  asynchronous?

Comment: @GabrielHeming no that is not asynch

Comment: @user3744203..yes i want alert after csv upload

Comment: You only could work like that if it's async. When your page refresh, you'll lost the event triggered and the trigger will start again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a jquery code that triggers right after page is completely loaded. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

You could put a flag to codebehind to see if you successfully uploaded the file. If your page reloads, you will lose all the javascript you have written before the postback event. So this wouldnt work;

```
$("#upload").click(function(){
$(window).bind("load",function(){
alert("done"); });});
```

You could try putting something as flag (like `isTrue`) right after you completed the uploading process. After the postback the code below would work;

```
$(function(){ if(isTrue){ alert("my alert"); }  });
```

Comment: how about $.when() and $.then() jquery function?

Comment: If you submit the form, you will lose all javascript functions and promises.